# Fuzzy Logic in Finance

Tags: mathematical-finance

Has fuzzy logic been commercially applied in finance fields and has it been successful ?
 I have got knowledge that it has been applied in Algorithmic trading and operational risk, but I want to know what are the other fields where they have been applied successfully on a commercial basis

Comment: -1: This is not a MO question!

Comment: Si, it is: #12401.  Why do you think it's not a _good_ MO question?

Comment: I agree somewhat with Charles.  To be a _good_ MO question, I would hope the poster would describe fuzzy logic, describe their thoughts on its applications to finance, etc.

Comment: I've also been told that non-standard analysis apparently has some applications!

Comment: @Zev: if by non-standard analysis you mean working in the reals extended by some nilpotent elements, then yes, that's extremely useful and applicable.

Comment: I agree that this isn't a good question as written. Without any indication of why you'd expect an interesting answer, it feels like a random "Is there a relationship between X and Y?" question. It's not clear why the question is being asked or what the asker hopes to get out of it. If I weren't a moderator or if there were already some close votes, I would vote to close until the question was edited to include more explanation (like what Theo suggested).

Comment: I think the problem is not that much with the question as it is with fuzzy logic itself (see wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic ). It is a mathematical theory, famous in other areas, toward which mathematicians (including me) are rather skeptical. So perhaps a better (yet boarder and vaguer) question is: Is fuzzy logic interesting?

Answer (score 3):

Not to my knowledge

Comment: This answer is quite amazing... You could reuse it on most questions :D

Comment: Well I work in the field, but I realize that my answer may seem quite vague, anyway I was honest while posting it and I am glad to learn from "vonjd" that there exist some application of fuzzy logic in mathematical finance. 
Regards

Comment: Well, not _you_, Mariano. :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually it has - in combination with Neural Nets. The NN is used to evaluate the fitness of fuzzy trading rules. A company that does these kinds of things is Siemens (esp. their research department 'Corporate Technology'). Siemens uses NNs quite successfully for their own trading/hedging commodities (e.g. copper, electricity)

**Supplement:** As a starting point please have a look at:
Siekmann, S.; Neuneier, R.; Zimmermann, H.G.; Kruse R.: Neuro Fuzzy Systems for Data Analysis, In: Computing with Words in Information / Intelligent Syst. 2; Eds.: Zadeh L. A., Kacprzyk J.;p. 35-74; Physica Verlag; 1999

Especially one of the authors, Dr. Hans-Georg Zimmermann is one of the most renowned experts in Neural Networks and Neural mathematics.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more how the fuzzy trading rules work? Mathematical details would be good...

Answer (score 3):

- Fuzzy Logic in Financial Management - InTechOpen

  URL:http://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs/32889.pdf
- Industrial and commercial applications of fuzzy logic

  URL:https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-56920-0_22
- Fuzzy Logic in Financial Analysis

  URL:http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540232131
- Fuzzy Logic (Finance) blog

  URL:http://what-when-how.com/finance/fuzzy-logic-finance/